# Perl script to grep for always block and print the specified lines

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep

I need to fetch the files , read line by line and search for always_ff block.
If always_ff is present, then i need to print the specific lines from inside the found always_ff block

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $file ('*.sv')
{
   open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;
   while (<$fh>) {
     print scalar <$fh> if /begin/;
   }
}
```

The file has :

```
always_ff @(negedge clk )
    begin
       if (!clk)
       begin
          p1 <= 1'b0;
       end
       else
       begin
         p1 <= disable_ff;
       end
    end

always_ff @(negedge clk)
    begin
       if (!clk)
       begin
          p2<= enable;
       end
       else
       begin
          p2 <= disable_ff;
       end
    end
```

Expected result:

```
p1 <= disable_ff
p2<= enable
p2 <= disable_ff;
```

Actual result coming :

```
if (!clk)
  p1 <= disable_ff;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, very good that you have tried to use CODE TAGS. Use it more clearly eg--> 1 section of code tags for only input and 1 section of code tags only for expected output then your question will be more clear. Also on SO we encourage people for posting their efforts also in their posts so kindly do so.

Comment: Why do you tag this [tag:awk] [tag:sed] [tag:grep] if you are looking for a Perl solution?

Comment: i have tried using perl , with little modification , code seems to work fine. grep and awk really makes our work easy. i would love to learn about awk and sed. Hence tagged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use the range operator with patterns that match the start and the end of the section. Looking at your input data I would suggest:

- start: match "always_ff" plus white space, i.e. `/always_ff\s+/`
- end: empty line, i.e. `/^\s*$/`
- in the block: print lines with assignment, i.e. `/<=/`

Quote from [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

> In scalar context, `..` returns a boolean value. The operator is bistable, like a flip-flop, ... It is false as long as its left operand is false. Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false again.

Something like this

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/always_ff\s+/../^\s*$/) {
        print if /<=/;
    }
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
always_ff @(negedge clk )
    begin
       if (!clk)
       begin
          p1 <= 1'b0;
       end
       else
       begin
         p1 <= disable_ff;
       end
    end

always_ff @(negedge clk)
    begin
       if (!clk)
       begin
          p2<= enable;
       end
       else
       begin
          p2 <= disable_ff;
       end
    end
```

Test output:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
          p1 <= 1'b0;
         p1 <= disable_ff;
          p2<= enable;
          p2 <= disable_ff;
```

For your use case of reading `*.sv` files replace `<DATA>` from my test code with `<STDIN>` and use the following shell command line:

```bash
$ cat *.sv | perl script.pl
```

Comment: If I understand your new requirement correctly, then you would need 3 changes: (1) before the while loop `my $out;`, (2) after the if: `$out = $1 if /always_ff\s+@\((\w+)/;`, (3) after the print `print "OUT=${out}\n" if /^\s*$/;`